# Route between 2 virtual subnets

Tags: networking, routing, virtualbox, subnet

I need to create two subnets within virtualbox (subnet 1: 192.168.56.0/24 subnet 2: 192.168.60.0/24). Machines in those two subnets need to ping each other. So for example the machine 192.168.56.103 can ping 192.168.60.5. What's the best method to get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create the subnets, set up routing.

Comment: that's the problem. The subnets are already created but how do I set up the routing?

Comment: `route add <network> gw <gateway>`
or if you bridged them, then `route add <network> dev <interface>`

Answer (score 3):

You need a router between the networks, i.e. a virtual machine with two network interfaces, one for each network. Let's say the interfaces on the router have addresses `192.168.56.1` and `192.168.60.1` on `subnet1` and `subnet2`, respectively. On the hosts on `subnet1` add a route to `subnet2` like this:

```
ip route add 192.168.60.0/24 via 192.168.56.1
```

and on all hosts on `subnet2`:

```
ip route add 192.168.56.0/24 via 192.168.60.1
```

The virtual machine working as a router can be a very simple Linux machine, the kernel does the routing, so no user space programs are needed. Packet forwarding on Linux is disabled by default, however. The following command enables forwarding:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

None of these commands make the settings persistent; how to do that depends on the Linux distribution.